# Best method to check if a value of a String is null in Java

Tags: java, string, null

there are many implementation in how to check whether a String value is null and I'm really confused what to use!

These are my searches so far:

1. `if(myString == null){}`
2. `Objects.equals(null, myString);`
3. `ObjectUtils.isEmpty(myString)`
4. `myString.equals(null)`
5. `myString.compareTo(null);`

---

**NOTE:** This is all about performance, reliable coding, fail-safe and other security purposes!

**Updated:** myString is dynamic, what if it was null, some of the implementation above will throw NullPointerException!

Answer (score 9):

Just use a simple `==`. There's no need to overcomplicate this.

Comment: sorry if my question was not clear, but I was having NPE when comparing it when myString is null, I have updated my question. Thanks! i guess == is not fail safe

Comment: @djrumix123 `==` **IS** fail safe in this case because you don't access any member of a potentially null string. `string1.equals(string2)` is not: It will throw a NPE if `string1` is null.
The problem with `==` is that it compares references, so it is valid to determine if a string is null or not but it is not pertinent to compare if two string have the same value.

Comment: @djrumix123 as C.Champagne said  - checking `myString != null` is the safest approach, and probably the best performing one too (you're just checking the reference's identity).

Answer (score 8):

Another Option if you are using Java 8 you can use [Optional::ofNullable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-)

```
Optional.ofNullable(myString).isPresent()// true if not null, false if null
```

You can even use :

```
Optional.ofNullable(myString)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("If null throw an exception"));
```

There are many Options, just read the documentation

---

But as [Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49295321/5558072) mention in his answer `==` is enough in your case.

Comment: @djrumix123 the new features also can help you a lot ;)

Comment: i'll try this though!

Answer (score 5):

1. `if(myString == null)`

   Easiest and right way.
2. `Objects.equals(null, myString)`

   A right way, its implemention is based on 1.
3. `ObjectUtils.isEmpty(myString)`

   Not sure which `ObjectUtils` you are working with, but it seems to check `myString` is empty, not null.
4. `myString.equals(null)`

   This does not work when `myString` is null, NPE will be thrown.
5. `myString.compareTo(null)`

   This does not work when `myString` is null, NPE will be thrown.

Answer (score -1):

`

```
String results;
if(results==null ||results.length()==0) {

}
```

`

Comment: This will not compile, as `results` is uninitialized. Even if it worked, `results==null` would cover the OP's requirements, which have already been covered in previous answers.